# Async parallel final callback doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, callback

I do have a async parallel block to execute two queries into MongoDB.
on each step of function(callback) I have a valid return result, no any errors are firing. I did debug and all steps are working except that final callback not firing and I can't event reach with breakpoint to its condition.
Does anybody have idea what that may happen?

```
async.parallel([

// first Query
function(callback){
  this._game.findOne({'_id': gameId}, function(err, result){
    if(err){return callback(err);}
    else if(result) {
      callback(null, result);
    }
  });
},

// second Query
function(callback){
  this._player.findOne({'_id': playerId}, function(err, result){
    if(err){return callback(err);}
    else if(result) {
      callback(null, result);
    }
  });
}
],

  // Final callback to send all 2 Results -> which is not working...
  function(error, results){

    if(results){

      res.status(200);
      res.send(results);
    }
  }
);`
```

Comment: are you sure that `gameId` and `playerId` are defined  and in the scope of `async.parallel()` ?

Comment: Yes, 100% that findOne returns in both cases valid results, so I can console.log them... I even went by breakpoints to each of tasks, and there was no error.. but when main callback should fire, it just quicks..

Answer (score 1):

You're not dealing with the possibility that Mongo doesn't find any results. In this case it will call the callback with `err` and `result` as null. When this happens the functions that you're running in parallel don't call their callbacks, so the final function never runs. What you do in this case is up to you but you need to call the `callback` function with something.

The reason that you're not getting any results is most likely that playerId and gameId are strings and _id is by default an ObjectId. Add a `var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;`, then replace `playerId` with `ObjectId(playerId)` and you'll likely see results.

Comment: Mongoose requests are valid and return result in each parallel task, this is for sure... I can console.log and debug them step by step... no error, and valid result returns - 100%tested.

Comment: Ah, you should have mentioned you're using Mongoose, it prevents you from having to deal with the ObjectId thing. You've definitely seen valid `result` objects in both queries? What happens if you add an `else {callback(null);} to each if-else?

Comment: Sorry, if absence of mongoose mislead you. Yes, both queries return valid results so I can console.log them... I tried callback(null) and also callback() in both cases, final callback still not fired..

Comment: I think I see the problem. Rename your callback functions to something else and I think it'll work. Let me know and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: i think you should try to rename any thing you can to be sure that it is not a variable name colision ! @piemonkey : good catch !

Comment: I tried and changed those callback function to callbackReply .... 'function(callbackReply){ setTimeout(function (){ var result = 2+2; callbackReply(null, result);}, 500 ); }' but still final one not firing... ((

Comment: Hmm, I was running on a theory that since they're using `callback` internally you were using their variable rather than yours but if that doesn't work then it doesn't sound right. I can only guess that there's something wrong with your setup beyond what's in the code sample above. What happens if you get rid of the `setTimeout` calls and just call the callback synchronously?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would debug it :

```js
async.parallel([

// first Query
function(fq_callback){
  this._game.findOne({'_id': gameId}, function(fq_err, fq_result){
    if(fq_err){
      console.log('err from _game.findOne');
      return fq_callback(fq_err);
    }
    else if(fq_result) {
      console.log('result from _game.findOne');
      fq_callback(null, fq_result);
    }
  });
},

// second Query
function(sq_callback){
  this._player.findOne({'_id': playerId}, function(sq_err, sq_result){
    if(sq_err){
      console.log('err from _player.findOne');
      return sq_callback(sq_err);
    }
    else if(sq_result) {
      console.log('result from _player.findOne');
      sq_callback(null, sq_result);
    }
  });
}
],

  // Final callback to send all 2 Results -> which is not working...
  function(fn_error, fn_results){
    console.log('in final callback');
    if(fn_error) console.log('we have error');
    if(fn_results){
      console.log('we have results');
      res.status(200);
      res.send(results);
    }else{
      console.log('we have NO results');
    }

  }
);
```

Comment: Tried your suggested way also, console logs only  _'result from _game.findOne'_ and _'result from _player.findOne'_  but neither _'in final callback'_ nor _'we have results'_ nor _'we have no results'_ printed....

Comment: This is very strange ! have you the last version ?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly as yours... Most strange that it's NOT firing any error... npm, node, mongoose, async are all updated...

Comment: Have you tried whit classic `setTimeout` functions ?

Comment: Yeah, I did tried those classic setTimeout samples, but not working.. really confused..